# Android Displaying a Progress Dialog from a class which is not in the UI thread

Tags: android, dialog, ui-thread

I define this method in a RecordTable class, which is not an Activity.
I call it from the main UI thread and pass a valid UI thread context as parameter. 
Of course, it does not work with the message:
`java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`

I saw in other post they recommend using `runOnUiThread` instead of `new thread` but since the class is not an activity `runOnUiThread` is not available.

Starting the Dialog outside the runnable() does not work either.

**Has anyone got this problem and found how to solve it?**

```js
public synchronized void scrollUp(final Context context, final ArrayList<Record> list, final int count) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            setScrolling(true);
            ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", context.getResources().getString(R.string.loading_msg), true);
            int n = Math.max(mViewStartIndex - count, 0);
            for(int i = mViewStartIndex - 1; i >= n; i--) {
                RecordTable.this.addFirstRow(list.get(i));
                RecordTable.this.removeViews(RecordTable.this.getChildCount() - 1, 1);
            }
            pd.dismiss();
            setScrolling(false);
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: did you try context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(etc..)) ?

Comment: @MuratNafiz I just tried, `runOnUiThread` is not available under `context`

Comment: you can cast your context to your Activity. Like:
((YourActivityName) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() ...
Where 'YourActivityName' is the activity which you are passing context

Comment: @MuratNafiz I just tried it, and it does not give any error, but the Progress dialog is not shown and the app gets an ANR

Answer (score 2):

Given the code I would suggest use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). 
Take a look at the documentation for AsyncTask.

Carry out the work you want on a different thread in the `doInBackground(....)` function with periodic calls to `progressUpdate`, which always runs on the UI thread. Much simpler to implement and you don't have to worry about creating new threads. AsyncTask does it for you.

Comment: I am leaving your suggestion as a last resort. I am sure it will work, I use AsyncTask for other stuff.:::: But it really hurts me to have to create a new class to run 6 lines of code, just because I want to display a Progress dialog ... :-(

Comment: On second though, in this specific case I cannot use AsyncTask, because the `for` loop manipulates a TableLayout, adding and deleting TableRows. And doInBackground() cannot deal with UI elements.

Comment: yes indeed doInBackground does not have accesst to UI thread but onProgressUpdate does. so in your for loop when you want to manipulate the table layout make a call to progressUpdate instead and do the manipulation in there as it runs on the UI Thread.

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I think that forfeits the whole purpose of using AsyncTask, which is not blocking the UI thread with background work.

Comment: this will not block the UI thread. read the documentation on AsyncTask. doInbackground is working on a seprate thread whilst, preExecute, postExecute, porgressupdate are on UI thread

Comment: You said it yourself, the onProgressUpdate does not run in a separate thread, only doInBackground. So if I follow your suggestion and do the TableLAyout work in onProgrssUpdate, I will not be using at all the separate thread. Moreover, I will need to keep the doInBackground() looping on empty until I finish the TableLayout update.

Comment: as a general rule if you want to do any time consuming tasks they should be in a separate thread. But if you want to do something to the UI then you need access to UI thread. I don;t know why you would run an empty loop in the other thread. Post your code please so I can uderstand

Comment: I posted the only code I have in the question. I did not move to AsyncTask because I don't see the point now. If you don't run an empty loop in doInBAckground() the AsyncTask finishes and excutes onPostExecute().

Answer (score 0):

```
ProgressDialog pd;
Context context;

public synchronized void scrollUp(Context context, final ArrayList<Record> list, final int count) {
this.context = context;
new Thread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
    setScrolling(true);
    hand.sendEmptyMessage(0);                
    }
  }
}).start();

int n = Math.max(mViewStartIndex - count, 0);
for(int i = mViewStartIndex - 1; i >= n; i--) {
RecordTable.this.addFirstRow(list.get(i));
RecordTable.this.removeViews(RecordTable.this.getChildCount() - 1, 1);

pd.dismiss();
setScrolling(false);
}


Handler hand = new Handler() 
{
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
    {
              pd = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", context.getResources().getString(R.string.loading_msg), true);
    }
}
```

try this it may help you....
if you want to create any dialog or Toast in a class handler will handle this...

Comment: the main reason I run a `runnable()` is to perform the for loop without blocking the UI thread. You put all the code outside the runnable. :::: I am also pretty sure the handle is only a solution if you are running inside some Activity. I am not. This is running from within the RecordTable class :::: The `pd.dismiss()` in your solution will not work, the same way `ProgressDialog.show()` did not work for me.